# Forcing the core-drawer-panel to be closed on startup

Tags: polymer

I'm using core-drawer-panel to show a left-hand menu and right-hand content. I want the menu to be closed when I open the page by default.  I tried setting responsiveWidth to 9999px, which works, but the drawer is quickly shown, then hidden, every time I go to the page.  Is there a style I can apply or JS I can run before polymer is "stable" to get it to hide the menu?

Answer (score 1):

Ah, this is fixed in 0.2.4: https://github.com/Polymer/core-drawer-panel/commit/68a2fc20235d5dad52cee806d29a76d9627b0ab8 but I was only using 0.2.3. Thanks for playing.