# Polymer, force core-drawer-panel drawer closed on ready

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, polymer, shadow-dom

I am attempting to force the drawer of core-drawer-panel closed on polymer ready.  Currently I have a core-drawer-panel as part of a custom element I am defining.  I have tried the following:

"drawer" is the ID of the core-drawer-panel element.

```
<core-drawer-panel id="drawer" drawerWidth="155px" touch-action="pan-y" selected="main" narrow>

Polymer({
   ready: function(){
      this.$.drawer.togglePanel();
      this.$.drawer.closePanel();
   }
});
```

Neither of the two functions above seem to trigger the drawer closed at start, or seem to trigger it at all.  They do reference the function correctly.  I tried `console.log(this.$.drawer.togglePanel);` and get the correct function printed.  Besides performing some CSS hackery can anyone tell me what I may be doing wrong?

I was able to get this working by forcing narrow layout e.g. `forceNarrow="true"`, but this does not seem to solve my issue efficiently.

EDIT: I have also seen this related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23686403/forcing-the-core-drawer-panel-to-be-closed-on-startup).  But forcing responsiveWidth to a large number doesn't seem to solve the problem....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm, as far as I understand, `togglePanel();` and `closeDrawer()` only work when the core-drawer-panel element is in narrow mode.

To force your component to be in narrow mode, you seem to add the `narrow`attribute, but as far as I know `narrow`is only a getter, i.e. to force narrow mode you should use `forceNarrow=true`

Anyway, the `ready()` event don't seem the good place to force that kind of behaviour. I tried to do the opposite thing, setting `forceNarrow=true` and open the drawer on loading.
It didn't work with `ready()` but it worked well with `domReady`. See element lifecycle methods in the doc : https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#lifecyclemethods

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

There's a undocumented `hidden` property.

Just do:

```
Polymer({
   ready: function(){
      this.$.drawer.hidden = true;
   }
});
```